# Why is it valid to use the residue theorem to compute the inverse z-transform, even though the z transform is discrete?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, inverse-function, signal-processing, z-transform

I understand how to use the [residue method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/residue-method-to-calculate-inverse-z-transform) to compute an inverse z-transform of an elementary function easily enough.  I'm confused however, because, from reading on Wikipedia, it seems this method is based on the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) from complex analysis (which I don't fully understand), which itself is based on [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) (which seems to be a generalization of the gradient theorem from vector calculus).

All of these theorems deal with integrals of continuous functions though.  The z-transform is discrete though -- $Z(x(n)) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n)z^{-n}$, where $x(n)$ is discrete.

How does it make sense to apply those theorems about complex line integrals to a discrete sum?

Comment: Looks like it is all based on reparameterizing the corresponding Fourier integral. I may need some time to formulate an answer, but the short form is that the shift from discrete to continuous can help solve some problems.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think the question is "why" does it help, not "if" it helps.

Comment: The sequence $x(n)$ is discrete, but its transform $X(z)$ is continuous.